# glOrtho results are not what I expected

Tags: qt, opengl

I am a little perplexed as to the trouble I am having with `glOrtho()`. My code works in the following case:

```
// Scenario 1
...
glOrtho(0, _width, 0, _height, 0, 1);
...
glRasterPos2i(0, 0);
...
```

However, I am unhappy with this coordinate system, I would like it to use:

```
// Scenario 2
...
glOrtho(0, _width, -_height, 0, 0, 1);
...
glRasterPos2i(0, -_height);
...
```

Unfortunately, only changing the two lines above in my code leaves me with a blank screen. I assumed I did not understand how `glOrtho()` and `glRasterPos2i()` work, as I am fairly new to OpenGl, so I tried the following:

```
// Scenario 3
...
glOrtho(0, _width, -_height, 1, 0, 1);
...
glRasterPos2i(0, -_height);
...
```

And, to my surprise, it worked! Why is this? The above code is not sufficient for my purposes, so I will stick with scenario 1 unless I can solve my problem. Does anyone have any insight as to why Scenario 1 and 3 work, but Scenario 2 does not? According to my web searches, Scenario 2 should work, so I must misunderstand something.

If it helps, I am using `glDrawPixels()` to draw an image, where _height and _width are the height and width of the image.

I am using `Windows 7` and `Qt 4.7.4`.

If you need any more info, let me know.

edit: Typo in the original, it should read `glOrtho(0, _width, -_height, 0, 0, 1)` instead of `glOrtho(0, _width, _height, 0, 0, 1)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You raster position is on the corner of the window. My guess is that round-off error is causing the position to be clipped in some cases but not others.

I think that the answer is `glWindowPos()`, which was added in version 1.4. Like the name says, it sets the raster position directly in window coordinates, unaffected by the modelview and projection matrices. Importantly, the raster position will always be valid, even if the position is on or outside of the window bounds. The disadvantage is that you'll have to do the coordinate mapping yourself before calling `glWindowPos()`.

Comment: Thanks for your response. I think you must be correct. I'll look into glWindowPos and make a decision. We were hoping to change from Scenario 1 to Scenario 2 to avoid having to map to another coordinate system, but by your description, we may have to anyway. Thanks!